# Remounting MySQL under a new mount point

Tags: linux, mysql, mount, partition

/var/lib/mysql is mounted on partition / which is now full. Is there a way to mount this under /home/mysql for more disk space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stop MySQL
2. Move MySQL data from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/home/mysql`
3. Point MySQL to the new data directory
4. Start MySQL

It could be implemented like this (WARNING: **not** tested)

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
mv /var/lib/mysql /home/.
ln -s /home/mysql /var/lib/mysql
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

***Always*** have a backup before you start moving the data directory.

Comment: Running this now! :D

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd give it it's own mountpoint on it's own partition, which can be mounted to `/var/lib/mysql`.

Failing that, you do have the option of using a loopback filesystem, though it definitely does introduce some I/O delays that MySQL may notice. Only you can know if increasing I/O latencies a bit will harm your expected performance.

The rough procedure....

1. Use dd to create a loopback file somewhere.

   - `dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/mysql/datavol bs=1M count=4096`
2. Attach the file to a loopback device

   - `losetup /dev/loop0 /home/mysql/datavol`
3. Format the device as you will.

   - `mkfs.ext3 /dev/loop0`
4. Mount it somewhere

   - `mount /dev/loop0 /mnt`
5. Copy your data

   - `cp -a /var/lib/mysql/ /mnt/`
   - Other methods may be used, this is just one.
6. Clear /var/lib/mysql
7. Remount to /var/lib/mysql

   - `umount /mnt ; mount /dev/loop0 /var/lib/mysql`
8. Ensure that directory is owned by the right user

   - `chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

At that point, you should have a larger /var/lib/mysql actually hosted from your larger partition.