# Backing up Entire MySQL Directory

Tags: mysql, backup, rsync, database-backup

In regards to:

[Remounting MySQL under a new mount point](https://serverfault.com/questions/442218/remounting-mysql-under-a-new-mount-point/)

What would be the best way to backup MySQL data before moving the mount point? Can this be done with MySQL running? Would a simple rsync off to another server work?

Comment: WOuld you like to change just the mount point or also switch to another server ?

Comment: Just changing mount point. / is full

Comment: then the instruction from the post you already mentioned in your question are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also backup your mysql database directory using rsync just add -a option in your command to preserve owner & permission.

rsync -arvz source destination.

Comment: This may cause problems (including data corruption) if you do it while MySQL is running.

Answer (score 2):

#### Simple backup with MySQL downtime

1. Stop MySQL - `/etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. Backup data directory - `tar czf /var/backups/mysql-2012-10-25.tar.gz /var/lib/mysql`

#### Backup using XtraBackup

[Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/) can be used to take online hot (non-blocking) backups of your database.

Comment: Anyway to do this without stopping mysql? This is a production system with close to 3GBs worth of MySQL database information. That could be a lot of downtime to tar.

Comment: Yeah, I will edit the answer with an additional solution.

Comment: XtraBackup is non-locking on InnoDB tables but requires a read lock on all tables to do MyISAM.  If you have a mix of the two, the lock will only be in place while the MyISAM tables are being backed up.